# How do I hide HTML video controls for all the videos on one page

Tags: javascript, php, html5-video

I have a page filled with movies created using a php foreach loop like so:

```
   foreach ($movies as $movie) {

        $pos = strrpos($movie, '/');
        $id = $pos === false ? $movie : substr($movie, $pos + 1);
            $image = $lookup[pathinfo($movie, PATHINFO_FILENAME)] ?? $temp;
            $sub = $lookup2[pathinfo($movie, PATHINFO_FILENAME)];
            $withoutExt = preg_replace('/\\.[^.\\s]{3,4}$/', '', $id);
            $xml = simplexml_load_file($dir . '/xml/' . $withoutExt . '.xml');
        echo '<div class="grid-containerTest">';
        if (file_exists($dir . '/xml/' . $withoutExt . '.xml')){
        echo '<div class="grid-item item1"><h3>' . $xml->title . '</h3></div>';
        }else{
            echo '<div class="grid-item item1"><h3>' . $withoutExt . '</h3></div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="grid-item item2"><video width="300" height="400" poster="'. $image .'" preload="none" id="videoElement">';
        echo '<source src="'. $movie .'" type="video/mp4">';
        echo '<track src="' . $sub . '" kind="subtitles" srclang="en-US" label="English" />Your browser does not support HTML5 video.</video></div>';
        echo '<div class="grid-item item3">' . $xml->overview . '<br /><br />';
        echo "Added on: " . date("F d Y.", filectime($movie)) . '</div>';
        echo '<br /><br /></div>';
    }
```

Then I have some JS stored in the footer that hides the controls until a user hovers over them:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(window) {
        function setupVideo()
        {
            var v = document.getElementById('videoElement');
            v.addEventListener('mouseover', function() { this.controls = true; }, false);
            v.addEventListener('mouseout', function() { this.controls = false; }, false);
        }

        window.addEventListener('load', setupVideo, false);
    })(window);
</script>
```

It works fine. For the first video loaded into the page. The others are unplayable as there's no longer any controls on them. So what can I do to make sure it works for every video?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you can only use the same id attribute once on a page. An id is supposed to be unique. Instead of using **id="videoElement"**, I would recommend using a class (eg **class="videoElement"**).

Besides that document.getElementById only returns a single element, so your listeners won't be added to all elements. There are several ways to solve this. One would be looping through all elements and adding the listeners.

```
document.querySelectorAll('.videoElement').forEach(function (videoElement) {
    // Add listeners to video element: videoElement.addEventListener....
});
```

Or you could use event delegation here. You could set the events to the body and then check whether or not the target of the event is a videoElement.

```
document.body.addEventListener('mouseover', function (mouseEvent) {
    if (mouseEvent.target.getAttribute('class') === 'videoElement') {
        // show controls
    }
});
```